# Unable to debug go in vscode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger

I'm not able to debug a go file in vscode. I want to debug mrcorordinator.go in package main but the main package also contain other files.Here is the main package structure.

main

- diskvd.go
- lockc.go
- lockd.go
- mrcoordinator.go
- mrworker.go
- pbc.go
- pbd.go

while debugging mrcoordinator.go, I'm getting Error like this

```
Build Error: go build -o /home/sanketbondre/myspace/6.824/src/main/__debug_bin -gcflags all=-N -l .
diskvd.go:19:8: no required module provides package 6.824/diskv; to add it:
    go get 6.824/diskv
lockc.go:7:8: no required module provides package 6.824/lockservice; to add it:
    go get 6.824/lockservice
pbc.go:21:8: no required module provides package 6.824/pbservice; to add it:
    go get 6.824/pbservice
viewd.go:8:8: no required module provides package 6.824/viewservice; to add it:
    go get 6.824/viewservice (exit status 1)
```

Does anyone know how debug specific go file in vscode(here I want to debug mrcoordinator.go only).

Comment: Hi, I suggest you try to debug a smaller project first. If you get stuck, you can add the code you're trying to debug here. In this way, it'll be easier for us to help you, thanks!

Comment: Hi, It was the Issue with dlv debugger you have to create a launch file and build all plugins using go build -gcflags=all="-N -l". you can refer to this https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/1229   regards the Issue.

Comment: Good to hear you figured out and made a progress.

It looks like it's a build error - the go command invoked by delve was reporting the missing dependencies. Either missing/incomplete `go.mod` or, you intended to build in GOPATH mode and the delve didn't run in gopath mode. The suggested flag `-gcflags=all="-N -l"` was already supplied as shown in the Build Error you posted.